# findAll in spring boot GET method with condition

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, crud

I have a get method in spring boot this is my service  :

```
public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
        List<Customer> customers =  cutomerRepository.findAll();
        return customers;
    }
```

This Api return All customers, but what about if i need to filtering them ? where one of them contains X

example :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "rorororo",
    "lastName": "dfdfkd",
    "email": "gfhgfhdgfdh@kjkr",
    "mobileNumber": null,
    "invoices": null,
    "name": "rorororo",
    "deleted": false
}
```

This is the shape of json, and i need to return where deleted = false and when its equal true, not returing it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [spring-data-jpa](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/), you can write your own queries by adding [methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation) (using a set of [keywords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords)) to your repository.

For your example `return customers where deleted = false`, you can write the following method :

```java
List<Customer> findByDeletedFalse();
```

Comment: and how can implement it? and where

Comment: You just need to add this method in your existing repository `CutomerRepository`

Comment: and by self will under stand that i need the customer where deleted = false ? thats weird !!

Comment: Look at the documentation links in my answer. Spring Data Jpa parses the *method name* to create the query. So you must use this syntax `findBy{FieldName}{Value}`, by using this syntax, spring data jpa can build the query `where deleted = false`